Clamp for tightening chains
What is the name of the base tool that was used in this custom tool?

https://tractiontracks.com/store/Tract-T-Tool%E2%84%A2-p266368366

It looks like someone took the base tool (red) and added eye bolts with welded hooks (black).
I've seen the base clamping tool before, but I don't remember what it's called.
Source: Jesse Muller - Installing and testing steel Over The Tire Tracks for a skidsteer (YouTube)

It looks like a ratchet load binder is what you are looking for.
E.g. Dynaline RATCHET LOAD BINDER,1/4 IN X 5/16 IN
